# Thinking sphinx not rendering results in order of 'relevance'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Thinking sphinx documentation says that it automatically sorts the results based on relevance. What is its relevance metric ? How can we define our own relevance metric for the system ?

Example : I have a db in which one entry is Windows XP & it contains a reference to Microsoft. I also have an entry for Microsoft itself. So when I query Microsoft , I should get Microsoft result first & then the XP one.
But I get XP result first & then of Microsoft.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: What does your index look like?  If you don't specify any weights, Sphinx will rank all fields equally, then sort based on whatever internal criteria it uses (alphabetical, position in index, etc).  If you want one field to carry more weight than another, just give it a field weight greater than 1.

See http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#fieldweights for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`:expr` sorting mode](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sorting-modes). This is probably what you want.

If you really need to choose another relevance metric (and understand difference between relevance and sort order), there are [few metrics](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setrankingmode) you can choose from. I was able to select ranking mode from rails console when I was experimenting. I can't recall how, but it was nothing complicated.